# Javascript: How to pass an argument to a method being called without parentheses

Tags: javascript, methods, arguments, parentheses

Sorry for how stupid this is going to sound. My JS vocabulary is terrible and I had absolutely no idea what to search for.

I'm using jQuery.

So I've got this code:

```
var example = {
    open: function(element){
       alert(element.text());
    },
    init: function(){
        $("a").click(example.open);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){example.init();)
```

So here's the problem: I want to pass an argument to example.open() when I click the "a" element. It doesn't seem like I can, though. In order for the example.open method to just…exist on page-load and not just run, it can't have parentheses. I think. So there's no way to pass it an argument.

So I guess my question is…how do you pass an argument to a function that can't have parentheses?

Thanks so much.

Comment: is `element` the link or is it some other element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert another anonymous function:

```
var example = {
    open: function(element){
       alert(element.text());
    },
    init: function(){
        $("a").click(function()
        {
          example.open($(this));
        });
    }
};
```

You can also try this version because jQuery set the function's context (`this`) to the DOM element:

```
var example = {
    open: function(){
       alert($(this).text());
    },
    init: function(){
        $("button").click(example.open);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the anchor through its own handler:

```
var example = {
    open: function( element ){
       alert(element.text());
    },
    init: function(){
      $("a").on("click", function() {
        example.open( $(this) );                           
      });
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  example.init();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery binds the HTML element that raised the event into the `this` variable, you just have to pass it as a regular parameter:

```
var example = {
    open: function(element){
       alert(element.text());
    },
    init: function(){
        $("a").click(function() {
            // jQuery binds "this" to the element that initiated the event
            example.open(this);
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){example.init();)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you actually want to do;
however, I can give a try:

```
var example = {
open: function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   alert($(event.target).text()+' : '+event.data.x);
},
init: function(){
    $("a").bind('click',{x:10},example.open);
}
};

$(example.init);
```

**demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/rahen/EM2g9/2/

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

---

There are several ways to handle this:

1. **Wrap the call in a function:**

   ```
   $('a').click( function(){ example.open( $(this) ) } );
   ```

   Where `$(this)` can be replaced by your argument list
2. **Call a different event creator function**, which takes the arguments as a parameter:

   ```
   $('a').bind( 'click', {yourvariable:yourvalue}, example.open );
   ```

   Where open takes a parameter called `event` and you can access your variable through the `event.data` (in the above it'd be `event.data.yourvariable`)

### Errors and Other Info

---

However your `element.text()` won't just work unless `element` is a jQuery object.  So you can jQueryify the object before passing it to the function, or after it's received by the function:

1. jQuery the *passed* object:

   ```
   function(){ example.open(this) } /* to */ function(){ example.open($(this)) }
   ```
2. jQuery the *received* object:

   ```
   alert(element.text());           /* to */ alert($(element).text());
   ```

That said, when calling an object without parameters `this` will refer to the object in scope (that generated the event).  So, really, if you don't need to pass extra parameters you can get away with something like:

```
var example = {
    open: function(){           // no argument needed
       alert($(this).text());   // this points to element being clicked
    },
    init: function(){
       $("a").click(example.open);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
   example.init();
});                             // your ready function was missing closing brace '}'
```